# How can I get total profit in this situation?

Tags: excel

[image]
I want to get total profit of C station in Sep and Oct not using indirect function. I really have no idea because date parts are merged. Help me Please...

Comment: You are supposed to store the data in a format that is designed for processing. You are not supposed to analyze formatted reports based on that data. If this table is in fact a pivot table, you can get its parts with [`GETPIVOTDATA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f). If this is just a table manually formatted from source data, use the source data for your lookups. If this table is the only table you have in electronic form, revise your process so that you store the data differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a helper column to get the month then you can use sumproduct.

In your Helper column use the formula

```
=IF(D4<>"",MONTH(D4),C3)   // assuming C is the helper column
```

Drag this down and you should get month number next to the date.

Then use sumproduct to sum the values.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C:C=9)*(E:E="C")*F:F)
```

[image]